# Xamarin C# - How can I connect blob storage account name and key to a preference?

Tags: c#, xamarin, preferences, blobstorage

Under my Services i have a data store to which you need to connect via blob storage account name and key. I want to save the account name and key to settings via Preferences from Xamarin.Essentials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to store the key for your items in `Preferences` or storing the Key (as in credentials) for connection. In case they are credentials, I would suggest to store them in [Secure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).

And Note: `Preferences` just could store following data format.

- bool
- double
- int
- float
- long
- string
- DateTime

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue